# Player object glitching around when there is a low framerate Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, rigidbody

I just started to make this game, it runs fine on my computer. 60fps, but when I tested it on another computer, with lower fps, the player just started to jitter and glitch around a lot. The game is basically unplayable like that, and I want to make sure that everyone who plays my game will be able to enjoy the full experience. I have pasted the specific part of the code for the movement below.

```
void Update () {

    rb.AddForce (Vector3.forward * ForwardSpeed);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A) && side > maxSideLeft) {
        rb.AddForce (-Vector3.right * Speed);
        side -= 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D) && side < maxSideRight) {
        rb.AddForce (Vector3.right * Speed);
        side += 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && level < maxLevelHeight) {
        rb.AddForce (Vector3.up * Speed);
        level += 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S) && level > minLevelHeight) {
        rb.AddForce (-Vector3.up * Speed);
        level -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scene1");
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be moving the player in the `Update()` method, applying direction and speed. For smooth movement, ***you also need to accommodate for the time in between updates***.

Consider this: your telling your player to move by a set distance every time you perform an `Update()`. We will say your hardware is fast enough to perform `Update()` 60 times per second. If you play your game using hardware that is only fast enough to perform `Update()` 30 times per second, you will only get to tell the player to move *half as many times* as before. Using *only* speed, your player would only be able to move *half the distance* in the same amount of time.

The solution is quite simple. You use the time since the *last* `Update()` as a multiplier, to ensure smooth movement, regardless of hardware. Unity provides this value as `Time.deltaTime`. Simply replacing `Speed` with `Speed * Time.deltaTime` should ensure smooth movement.

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea why I did not do that. I had a different movement script that implemented transform.translate and use Time.deltatime for that, but for some reason I just didn't do it here.

Comment: This wrongly indicates that the OP should continue to use Update for physics movement. You should be using FixedUpdate.

Comment: @Jack, than make the changes for review. I won't make such edits from phone.